# Is array_key() the fastest solution for this?

Tags: php, performance, array-key

I'm writing an application for my research which deals with very big arrays and lots of iterations on their values. For reducing the calculation time, I'm implementing several improvements in the codes. Right now, after several improvements, the calculation time is still a bit high. The `array_key()` function is the one that consumes **almost half** of the calculation time. Is there any better substitute for that?

I'm creating an example which is a simple version (without iteration loops) of what I need to improve:

```
$bigArray=array_fill(0,1000000,0);
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    $rnd=mt_rand(0,1000000);
    $bigArray[$rnd]=1;
}

$start=microtime(true);
$list=array_keys($bigArray,1);
$end=microtime(true);

echo $end-$start;
```

The outcome is something like `0.021490097045898` seconds. Does anybody know a faster way to do this? Even very small improvement will be helpful since this kind of calculation would go for hundreds of thousands of rounds and sometimes the time reaches up to 30 seconds and half of it is for the `array_key()` function as described above.

BTW, I'm running the script on a Dual Core (Intel) E8500 @3.16GHz,3.17GHz with 8Gb RAM, the OS is Windows 7 64-bit (just in case).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 0.02 is pretty fast for PHP considering that array size :)

Comment: Yes I know, but as I mentioned, due to my huge calculations, I'm looking for any possible substitute that is faster :).

Comment: Considering you've got an array of 1 million elements, and are searching for 10 elements with the value 1, 0.02 seconds is pretty good.

Comment: Try using an opcode cache like APC, it should speed up your script

Comment: How about a totally different approach? Don't create the big array, just add 10 (your loop size) random elements (in your range) to an array (just append, random is the value `$array[] = mt_rand()`) and then `array_unique`. This is cheap because your array is small.

Comment: As a result you get list of maximum ten random numbers, right? Couldn't you just generate random number ten times and put each into an array (as a key to be sure there is no duplicates)? :)

Comment: Crystal balling: if (1) you are only interested in keys with a certain value, not grouping the keys for all possible values and (2) you know the values beforehand, it stands to reason that speed could be gained from checking the value directly after calculation and storing it separately. Other then that, this seems about what you can get, but under certain circumstances and conditions using a [SPLFixedArray](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) may provide some speedup.

Comment: would an indexed db lookup be faster? HEAP, or not.

Comment: As I said, I just created this example to show you what the content looks like. My arrays are fed by user input and I don't have control on them, neither of the 1s and 0s in them. But I need to know were those 1s are in that arrays.

Comment: @Dagon, it's not! I have done performance test on that and the array was faster (similar test: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430539/mysqli-query-vs-php-array-which-is-faster).

Comment: was that based on the HEAP storage engine?

Comment: @Dagon, no it was not on `HEAP`. I only have these on my machine: `MRG_MYISAM, MyISAM, BLACKHOLE, CSV, MEMORY, ARCHIVE, InnoDB, PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA`

Comment: @Wrikken, I'll check `SPLFixedArray` and let you know the results.

Comment: The key lookup in a database table with 1 million records would be very fast if the table is properly indexed, probably milliseconds. So unless you're inserting a million records on each request, that would be the fastest solution

Comment: @OneTrickPony, the problem is that, as you said, to use the database I need to insert all values into the tables first, then do the key look up. That inserting adds more time that makes the entire process slower.

Comment: @SAVAFA: if it's really just 1's and 0's, `array_filter()` performs about twice as fast as the `array_keys()` here BTW.

Comment: is php the best approach to this project, its hardly the traditional domain of a language designed for Web development

Comment: @Wrikken, Thanks. by adding `array_filter()` to the actual calculation, the time went down from `10.186648130417` to `8.5778539180756`

Comment: Might want to have a look at https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to @Wikken from the comments:

> if it's really just 1's and 0's, array_filter() performs about twice as fast as the array_keys() here.

It is really helpful and performs the job fast. Reduced the time by %20 in my case. Thanks Wikken!